# IBPY get correct historical volume data

Tags: algorithmic-trading, interactive-brokers, ibpy

I am trying to get historical data from IBPY.
I get it, but the volume is extremely low to the point it's useless. 
I would like to know how to get the correct historical volume estimation.

I'm executing the following code:

```
from ib.opt import Connection, message
from ib.ext.Contract import Contract
from ib.ext.Order import Order
from time import sleep, strftime

def historical_data_handler(msg):
    print(msg)

connection = Connection.create(port=7496, clientId=999)
connection.register(historical_data_handler, message.historicalData)
connection.connect()

req = Contract()
req.m_secType = "STK"
req.m_symbol = "TSLA"
req.m_currency = "USD"
req.m_exchange = "AMEX"
endtime = strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')
connection.reqHistoricalData(1,req,endtime,"1 D","1 hour","TRADES",1,1)

sleep(5)
connection.disconnect()
```

and this is the output:

```
<historicalData reqId=1, date=20181123  16:30:00, open=333.21, high=333.33, low=331.04, close=332.92, volume=22, count=21, WAP=332.233, hasGaps=False>
<historicalData reqId=1, date=20181123  16:30:00, open=333.21, high=333.33, low=331.04, close=332.92, volume=22, count=21, WAP=332.233, hasGaps=False>
<historicalData reqId=1, date=20181123  17:00:00, open=332.93, high=334.2, low=327.0, close=328.2, volume=42, count=39, WAP=329.755, hasGaps=False>
<historicalData reqId=1, date=20181123  17:00:00, open=332.93, high=334.2, low=327.0, close=328.2, volume=42, count=39, WAP=329.755, hasGaps=False>
<historicalData reqId=1, date=20181123  18:00:00, open=329.0, high=330.37, low=327.96, close=327.96, volume=17, count=17, WAP=329.375, hasGaps=False>
<historicalData reqId=1, date=20181123  18:00:00, open=329.0, high=330.37, low=327.96, close=327.96, volume=17, count=17, WAP=329.375, hasGaps=False>
<historicalData reqId=1, date=20181123  19:00:00, open=328.5, high=328.6, low=326.07, close=326.07, volume=25, count=25, WAP=327.498, hasGaps=False>
<historicalData reqId=1, date=20181123  19:00:00, open=328.5, high=328.6, low=326.07, close=326.07, volume=25, count=25, WAP=327.498, hasGaps=False>
```

The data arrives, but the volumes of each row are impossibly low (~22 for hourly bars).

On their website:
https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/historical_bars.html#hd_what_to_show

it is stated that:

> Note: IB's historical data feed is filtered for some types of trades
>   which generally occur away from the NBBO such as combos, block trades,
>   and derivatives. For that reason the historical data volume will be
>   lower than an unfiltered historical data feed

However, the retrieved volumes are so low they are useless.

I suppose I'm not the first to need historical volume data, and there is probably a way to get it.
Can you please tell me how?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you subscribed to all the data? IbPy hasn't been supported for a very long time, if you're using a newer API version there would be issues.

Comment: Try changing exchange to SMART.

Answer (score 3):

Volume is reported in hundreds.  For example 22 is 2,200 shares.

For a reference see the Trader Workstation API Reference Guide or online [here](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/tick_types.html).